# Identifying and connecting continuous x,y trajectories in Python

Tags: python

I'm an inexperienced programmer trying to create a program to deal with some text files in Python. I'm currently working with single molecule trajectories, and the program that I use to track them spits out data that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNTTO.png). The first 3 columns are all that matters, and they are the frame number, x coordinate, and y coordinate. These are saved as a tab delimited text file, with a blank row between trajectories.

The problem is that occasionally my molecule tracking program will lose track of a molecule then find it again later, for example from the attached image it may later find a molecule that starts with frame number 25, x around 199, y around 124. I want to create a program that will identify when a molecule was lost and re-found, and stitch those trajectories together.

Does anyone have any advice on packages that may be useful, or even just a way to approach this that would be efficient in Python? I currently have numpy and pandas.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Please skim [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) to understand which questions are best for this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the packages you want - numpy and pandas. I'd recommend going through a few tutorials, starting with a basics numpy one, but focusing on pandas. Doing work like this in python is best done in an interactive notebook editor, so if you can install Jupyter/IPython that'll make your life way easier in the future. Also, build out your test datasets first and drop them in a file, so every day when you start you can import 1 file and have small, usable datasets ready to go (you'll have to use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) package probably)!